# PC game castle strike can't see full message window and therefore can't close it

Tags: gaming

I play a tutorial in Castle Strike and I can't close the message which tell me what to do because the part of the message window with close button is below the screen.

Comment: Alt-F4 can usually be used to exit any application. Enter can be used to trigger the default button and escape can usually be used to exit any window. If that doesn't work, try to move the window to access it, making it go full screen or maximizing the window.

Comment: No chance, there is no hotkey for close the message window in this game.

Comment: And window cannot be moved.

Comment: I've seldomly seen a game that couldn't be controlled by the keyboard. Try one of the keys you use for doing an action, such as spacebar, etc. Otherwise you'll need to contact their support.

Answer (score 0):

Try ALT+ENTER combination to make it fullscreen.

Comment: It is already fullscreen.

Comment: What resolution youre using on desktop? And in game?

Comment: 1920 x 1080 both game and desktop.

Comment: Alt+Space invokes the taskbar menu. Use ‘M’ for move, ‘S’ for (re)size, ‘N’ for minimize, ‘X’ for maximize, ‘R’ for restore, ‘C’ for close, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay now, with resolution 1280x1024, messages are full visible. The problem was that I change the resolution to unsupported resolution or resolution which has problem to display message windows correctly.

Comment: Did you change settings  or hardware  (or both)?

Comment: I changed game settings (but in notepad because in game change caused freeze).